# use Python requests or robobrowser to scrape data from aspx form

Tags: python, asp.net, scrape

I want to scrape data from an .aspx page at

```
https://www.clarkcountycourts.us/Anonymous/Search.aspx?ID=400
```

My problem is how to formulate the search parameters correctly to be used in a `<form>`.

I am trying to use python requests or robobrowser, but the form on that site is a bit complicated. I don't know how to "click" on radio buttons to select certain options. my first problem is that I want my crawler to "click" on the "search by" drop-down menu and select "party". I think I found the element on the website that performs this action:

```
<select id='SearchBy' name='SearchBy' onChange='SwitchCaseSearch(this.value, true)'  onKeyUp='SwitchCaseSearch(this.value, true)' LabelName='Search By:'>
```

and then there are several numerical values to give to `SwitchCaseSearch`. I think I want to execute the call `SwitchCaseSearch(1)`? i.e. switch to "party". Then I'd like to click on "business", and fill in a business name, e.g. "Bank of America". the relevant function is

```
<input type="radio" name="PartySearchMode" onclick="SwitchPartyType(this.value, true)" value="BusinessName" id="PartyBusinessOption" labelname="Party Search Mode:" labelvalue="Business Name" style="display: inline;">
```

how does one deal with this? do I actually have to "click" or is there another way of searching within the desired category? thanks!

---

EDIT: POST request sent by my browser when submitting the form.

[image: post request]

Comment: `robobrowser` wraps `requests`; using only the latter would mean you have to do the form parsing yourself, while `robobrowser` uses BeautifulSoup to do that work for you.

Comment: BeautifulSoup (so `robobrowser` here) will not execute JavaScript code for you; nothing will call `SwitchCaseSearch(1)` for you here.

Comment: That drop-down only drives what forms are actually shown in a browser; the HTML is all there for robobrowser to fill in. I'd simply ignore that select box and go straight for the right form elements.

Comment: If you want to automate JavaScript-driven forms, you either need to use a scraper with a JS interpreter or drive an actual browser, a la Selenium (or use something like Phantom which is sort of half-way between the two). The alternative is to figure out what the JS ends up doing (usually either by working it through manually, or logging the requests that a browser makes and reversing it from that) and do _that_ in `robobrowser`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ok cool that's basically what I wanted to know. it's a pain to find the right form elements! (never done before, as you might have guessed).

Comment: @abarnert i think the selenium option is overkill for my purposes. i'll try to find out what the JS does, as you said. I think I need to find out where the info collected from that type of field goes: `<input type='radio' name='PartySearchMode' onclick='SwitchPartyType(this.value, true)' value='BusinessName' id='PartyBusinessOption' LabelName='Party Search Mode:' LabelValue='Business Name'>` in the eventual call.

Comment: @abarnert: from a quick glance I'd say the forms are all there and all that that drop-down does is control which one is visible.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I didn't bother glancing; in this case, I suspect he can figure it out from my comment—and if not, he probably won't be able to write and maintain the code if I figure it out for him. (If it were something more interesting than HTML forms, I'd probably glance anyway, of course…)